# Passing parameter in Attribute class through contractor

Tags: c#, attributes

In my C# application, I am trying to pass parameter to the `Attribute` class through constructor.
But having compiler error
Here is the `Attribute` class

```
    public class ManageApplicationInsightsAttribute : JobFilterAttribute, IServerFilter
     {
        private ILogger<ManageApplicationInsightsAttribute> _logger;
        private TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;
       
        public ManageApplicationInsightsAttribute(TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
        }
        
        void IServerFilter.OnPerformed(PerformedContext filterContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In OnPerformed");
        }

        void IServerFilter.OnPerforming(PerformingContext filterContext)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("In OnPerforming");
        }
    }
```

Here is the usage class where I am trying to pass `TelemetryClient` object

```
    public class MyJob: IBackgroundJob
    {
        private TelemetryClient _telemetryClient;

        public MyJob(TelemetryClient telemetryClient)
        {
            _telemetryClient = telemetryClient;
        }

        [ManageApplicationInsights(_telemetryClient)]    
        public async Task Execute()
        {
            await _client.ProcessAllAsync(100);
        }
    }
```

I am getting error:

```
•CS0655: 'telemetryClient' is not a valid named attribute argument because it is not a valid attribute parameter type.
```

What I am missing here?

Thanks in advance.

I have googled it. But no suitable solution found.

Comment: That will never work because `_telemetryClient` isn't a constant value.

Comment: I also Googled it and only came up with [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/issues/992).

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve that?